# How to update my address throug _id in myAddresses mongodb nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The data :

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5da6ea7228cc5e07b48173b5"),
        "name" : "Joshi",
        "email" : "joshiga@gmail.com",
        "password" : "4emc8122",
        "phone" : "60000000001",
        "myAddresses" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5da6eb511e21bf07ce33b868"),
                "address" : "Office",
                "firstName" : "joshi",
                "lastName" : "g",
                "country" : "India",
                "city" : "VISAKHAPATNAM",
                "province" : "Andhra Pradesh",
                "postalCode" : 521344,
                "phoneNumber" : 8100000006.0,
                "address1" : "D.no:12,",
                "address2" : "santhi nagar, gurudwara"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5da6ec5e20a5db07da27fbc6"),
                "address" : "Home",
                "firstName" : "joshi",
                "lastName" : "g",
                "country" : "India",
                "city" : "Vijayawada",
                "province" : "Andhra Pradesh",
                "postalCode" : 521333,
                "phoneNumber" : 8000000006.0,
                "address1" : "D.no:11-41,",
                "address2" : "main road, kalidindi"
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

Comment: Post the code what you tried??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
CollectionName.update({'myAddresses._id': "Your ID"}, {'$set': {
    'myAddresses.$. address': 'updated Address'    
}}, function(err) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelName.update({
                "_id": req.params.id,
                "myAddresses": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "_id": req.params.addressId
                    }
                }
            }, {
                    $set: {

                        "myAddresses.$.address": req.body.address,
                        "myAddresses.$.firstName": firstName,
                        //add all fields

                    }

                })
```